# Find matrix given column and row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find a matrix with the required property when the column space contains: $[0,2,1]^T$,$[0,0,1]^T$ and the row space contains: $[1,1]^T$, $[2,1]^T$. How can this be easily done? The column space means that for the equation $Ax=b$ there is some $x$ that gets $[0,2,1]^T$,$[0,0,1]^T$ correct?

Comment: Your interpretation of column space is correct. You should be able to take the $3 \times 2$ matrix whose columns are $(0,2,1)^T$ and $(0,0,1)^T$.

Comment: The question asks for the 'required property of the matrix' so would that just be any matrix whose dimensions are 3x2?

Comment: Not necessarily. Not all $3 \times 2$ matrices will have that column span. In particular, the $x$-coordinate is zero for both those vectors, so could only take $3 \times 2$ matrices whose first row is zero.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. If the column space is a 3x1 vector then that means that A must be a 3xSomething matrix. And since the row space is a 2x1 vector, then that means that A^T must be a 2xSomething vector. Meaning A is a 3x2 matrix???

Comment: That is correct. The dimensions of the matrix must match as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

This technique doesn't necessarily generalize, but one thing we can do is simply insert the two vectors $\langle 0, 2, 1\rangle$ and $\langle 0, 0, 1\rangle$ into the columns of a matrix. This gives
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can check if $\vec{b}_1=\left\langle1,\,1\right\rangle\in\operatorname{Row}(A)$ and $\vec{b}_2=\left\langle2,\,1\right\rangle\in\operatorname{Row}(A)$ by checking the consistency of the two systems
\begin{align*}
A^\top\vec{x} &= \vec{b}_1 & A^\top\vec{x} &= \vec{b}_2
\end{align*}
Are these two systems consistent?